# Identify/block pornographic content in Images

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to know if google DLP has an option to identify / block pornographic content in images?
Looking to integrate with a DLP Engine that has these capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the documentation [Inspecting images for sensitive data](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/inspecting-images):

> Cloud Data Loss Prevention (DLP) can detect and classify sensitive
> data within an image. Using [infoType detectors](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/infotypes-reference) and optical
> character recognition (OCR), **Cloud DLP inspects a base64-encoded
> image for text, detects sensitive data within the text**, and then
> returns the locations of any sensitive data that it has detected.

**As a workaround to find explicit content** on the pictures you can use Cloud Vision API. Please have a look at the documentation [Detect explicit content (SafeSearch)](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-safe-search):

> **SafeSearch Detection detects explicit content such as adult content** or violent content within an image. This feature uses five
> categories (adult, spoof, medical, violence, and racy) and returns the
> likelihood that each is present in a given image. See the
> [SafeSearchAnnotation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#google.cloud.vision.v1.SafeSearchAnnotation) page for details on these fields.